# How to include the value of the query parameter in the email body using sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server

I am calling sp_send_dbmail and setting the query parameter. The resulting email includes the results of the query. I want the actual query (the value of the query parameter) to be appended to the email, so that the email will include the results and then the query itself at the end.

This will aid debugging.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/e2bef720-316b-4146-ad9f-cd6e1c93a310/

Comment: Did the example I gave you work?

Comment: I've not tried but I don't think it will cos my query is a stored procedure and it outputs via a select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the body of the email to be the query that you want and send the results as an attachment. For example:

```
DECLARE @sql_cmd NVARCHAR(max) = 
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.WorkOrder
              WHERE DueDate > ''2004-04-30''
              AND  DATEDIFF(dd, ''2004-04-30'', DueDate) < 2';
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',
@recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
@query =  @sql_cmd,
@body = @sql_cmd,
@subject = 'Work Order Count',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

Sources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx